# Entity Framework Core - ExecuteSqlCommand: MAX function returning wrong value

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to do a simple thing: to get the MAX of a column. Is quite simple, you know, just run SELECT MAX(column) FROM table;

The problem is when I try to do this in my .NET Core 2.1 project, using Entity Framework.

I have a function that should return the next value of a column.

```
private int getColumNextValue(string table, string column)
{
  string query = $"SELECT MAX({column}) + 1 FROM {table};";    
  return base.context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query);
}
```

The query is being generated correclty:

[image]

However, it's returning -1 instead of the real value.

[image]

But when I run the exact same query in Sql Server Management Studio, the result is correct:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: `MAX(ID) +1` can easily return duplicates if eg the latest row is deleted. That's why it's seldom used to generate IDs. Use `IDENTITY` or a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead. EF has no trouble working with IDENTITY values either. It *doesn't* have to know the IDs in advance to set up foreign keys. When a new root object and nested objects are added, EF will generate the appropriate statements to set all IDs according to the relations configured on the DbContext

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos; Thanks for the advice. I understand the identity strategy, but the point is that I'm dealing with a legacy database where it's creator didn't use `IDENTITY`, so I have to use the MAX+1 strategy... Sad but it's the reality. So, I need to execute an insert query into the legacy db through a secondary connection, that's why I need to run a query on the fly, without binding it to a model.

Comment: Dapper doesn't change the fact that MAX+1 creates duplicates. You'd still get them whether you used Dapper or straight ADO.NET SqlCommand. In fact, if you have more than 1 concurrent users, you risk both of them getting the same MAX value and trying to insert data using the same ID

Comment: In fact, EF Core offers the [HiLo key strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core#the-hilo-algorithm-in-ef-core) to safely generate IDs on the client.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, @PanagiotisKanavos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `QueryFirstOrDefault<int>` to solve my problem.
I wrote this helper method for reusable purpose:

```
private int GetColumNextValue(string table, string column)
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")))
  {
    string query = $"SELECT MAX({column}) + 1 FROM {table};";
    return conn.QueryFirstOrDefault<int>(query);
  }
}
```

I hope it can help other people.

Answer (score 2):

For `ExecuteSqlCommand`, it only return the number of rows affected. It would not run the query and return the result.

For a workaround, you could try like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }


    public async Task<T> ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(string rawSql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        var conn = Database.GetDbConnection();
        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = rawSql;
            if (parameters != null)
                foreach (var p in parameters)
                    command.Parameters.Add(p);
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            return (T)await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And use `ExecuteScalarAsync` like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    string query = $"SELECT MAX(SEQ) + 1 FROM [User];";
    var result = await _context.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(query);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You are opening the connection associated with the context, but not closing it afterwards, which is not good.